# How to remove the duplicate among 3 rows in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to remove these duplicate Team name which is appearing in both Team1 and Team2, Like Australia appearing in both Match 0,1 and opponent of Australia is same also the result in Winner.

```
       Match      Team1         Team2         Winner 
       0      Australia       England      Australia 
       1        England     Australia      Australia    
       2          India     Australia      Australia
       3        England         India        England
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.sort`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+sort&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+sort&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i59j0l3.2740j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to sort the columns on `axis=1` and then check with [`df.duplicated()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+duplicated&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+duplicated&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2251j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and use `~` to turn `False` to `True` so only non duplicated rows are `True`, and use as boolean mask.:

```
m=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Team1','Team2','Winner']],axis=1)).duplicated()
df[~m]
```

---

```
   Match      Team1      Team2     Winner
0      0  Australia    England  Australia
2      2      India  Australia  Australia
3      3    England      India    England
```

Comment: df[~m]  -- IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Comment: @Danraptor "index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match"  what are indexes of the orig df?

Comment: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  -- As i thought  you use np.sort it will change and store index according to sorted df  in m, but original df remain same so it will causes the Index Error . That's why by removing np.array Error will removed.

Comment: @Danraptor i am using `np.sort` to sort the columns over axis=1 , once sorted, `.duplicated()` will identify duplicates, the error you get is because the indexes of the orignal df aren't in order. so you can do a reset_index() and then check with `df[~m]` to preserve the indexes

Comment: Yes, you are right as I removed the NaN columns form the df but don't reset the index so that's why the error occurred, Thanks